# Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 1: Operation not permitted

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

This error occasionally occurs when using WKWebview in iOS16/17.
After this error occurs, WKWebview stop working and can only restart the app
It's very difficult to reproduce, so I can't debug it.

```
错误  19:05:54.142273+0800    MyApp    0x14711abe0 - [PID=38992] WebProcessProxy::requestTermination: reason=2
默认  19:05:54.142335+0800    MyApp    AuxiliaryProcessProxy::terminate: PID=38992
默认  19:05:54.142405+0800    dasd    Reported to CoreAnalytics <private>
默认  19:05:54.142714+0800    MyApp    Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 1: Operation not permitted
错误  19:05:54.142781+0800    MyApp    0x14711abe0 - [PID=38992] WebProcessProxy::processDidTerminateOrFailedToLaunch: reason=RequestedByClient
默认  19:05:54.142991+0800    MyApp    0x14711abe0 - [PID=38992] WebProcessProxy::shutDown:
默认  19:05:54.143228+0800    MyApp    0x14711abe0 - [PID=38992] WebProcessProxy::processWillShutDown:
默认  19:05:54.144607+0800    MyApp    0x146090120 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Trying to take RBS assertion 'XPCConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=38992
默认  19:05:54.146967+0800    runningboardd   Acquiring assertion targeting [xpcservice<com.apple.WebKit.WebContent([app<com.MyAppsuite.mmyapp.cooltt.inhouse((null))>:29257])>:38992:38992] from originator [app<com.MyAppsuite.mmyapp.cooltt.inhouse((null))>:29257] with description <RBSAssertionDescriptor| "XPCConnectionTerminationWatchdog" ID:32-29257-448570 target:38992 attributes:[
    <RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">
    ]>
默认  19:05:54.147241+0800    runningboardd   Assertion 32-29257-448570 (target:[xpcservice<com.apple.WebKit.WebContent([app<com.MyAppsuite.mmyapp.cooltt.inhouse((null))>:29257])>:38992:38992]) will be created as active
默认  19:05:54.151104+0800    MyApp    0x146090120 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Successfully took RBS assertion 'XPCConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=38992
默认  19:05:54.151326+0800    MyApp    0x146100180 - [PID=38992, throttler=0x14711add0] ProcessThrottler::Activity::invalidate: Ending foreground activity / 'WebPageProxy::runJavaScriptInFrameInScriptWorld'
默认  19:05:54.151468+0800    runningboardd   Calculated state for xpcservice<com.apple.WebKit.WebContent([app<com.MyAppsuite.mmyapp.cooltt.inhouse((null))>:29257])>:38992: running-active (role: UserInteractiveFocal)
默认  19:05:54.152013+0800    MyApp    0x146bec0e0 - [PID=38992, throttler=0x14711add0] ProcessThrottler::Activity::invalidate: Ending foreground activity / 'WebPageProxy::runJavaScriptInFrameInScriptWorld'
默认  19:05:54.152045+0800    MyApp    0x14711add0 - [PID=38992] ProcessThrottler::didDisconnectFromProcess:
默认  19:05:54.152081+0800    MyApp    0x1462284e0 - ~ProcessAssertion: Releasing process assertion 'WebProcess Foreground Assertion' for process with PID=38992
错误  19:05:54.152190+0800    MyApp    0x1200f0618 - [pageProxyID=649, webPageID=650, PID=38992] WebPageProxy::processDidTerminate: (pid 38992), reason=RequestedByClient
错误  19:05:54.152348+0800    kernel  5 duplicate reports for Sandbox: com.apple.WebKit.GPU(38846) deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.diagnosticd
错误  19:05:54.152365+0800    kernel  Sandbox: com.apple.WebKit.Networking(29277) deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.diagnosticd
默认  19:05:54.152406+0800    MyApp    0x146c54200 - [PID=0, throttler=0x14711add0] ProcessThrottler::Activity::invalidate: Ending foreground activity / 'View is visible'
默认  19:05:54.152439+0800    MyApp    0x15cecc800 -[WKWebView _processDidExit]
默认  19:05:54.153081+0800    runningboardd   Invalidating assertion 32-29257-448536 (target:[xpcservice<com.apple.WebKit.WebContent([app<com.MyAppsuite.mmyapp.cooltt.inhouse((null))>:29257])>:38992:38992](WebProcess38992)) from originator [app<com.MyAppsuite.mmyapp.cooltt.inhouse((null))>:29257]
默认  19:05:54.153148+0800    SpringBoard Received state update for 38992 (xpcservice<com.apple.WebKit.WebContent([app<com.MyAppsuite.mmyapp.cooltt.inhouse((null))>:29257])>:38992, running-active-NotVisible
默认  19:05:54.153254+0800    MyApp    0x15cecc800 (pageProxyID=649) -[WKWebView _cancelAnimatedResize] dynamicViewportUpdateMode 0
```